# Current available SRAM?

Tags: variables, sram

I've reached the limit on available SRAM memory. I need to "cut down" some variables, but I actually don't know how far I need to go with it.

Is there a way on measuring current available memory on program execution?

Comment: Start with moving string literals into the flash memory only (AVR based boards) - [Nick Gammon's article about it](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem)

Answer (score 2):

If you set "Show verbose output during compilation" in your IDE preferences, you'll see a message like the following in the IDE window's lower pane. The part I bolded is the amount of SRAM assigned:

> Sketch uses 2,148 bytes (6%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
>   **Global variables use 204 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory**, leaving 1,844 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

You can also include this function and print its result to get the same information on the terminal during run-time:

```
int freeRAM () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval;
  int v;
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);
}
```